# Iterating Group Stats Tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have been looking for a way to extract various stats for each group from a shp file which contains groups of points. I found that Group Stats tool is the way to do that. However I would like to iterate this tool over 100 shp files. Is there any way to do that in the QGIS python window?

Otherwise I have to merge all files then apply the tool. But this makes data very large and unmanageable.

I used code below to run items iteratively. Only issue I had, when I open the excel file, it throws me a "repair warning". After I click OK all calculations are there. But not sure why excel gives those warnings.

```py
import processing

...

for itemfeature in listofShps:
    outputfullpath = os.path.dirname(itemfeature)+ '\\' + os.path.basename(itemfeature)[:-4] + '.xlsx'
    processing.run('qgis:statisticsbycategories',
                   {'CATEGORIES_FIELD_NAME': [strCatagoryFieldName],
                    'INPUT': itemfeature,
                    'VALUES_FIELD_NAME': strValueFieldName,
                    'OUTPUT': outputfullpath} )
```

Comment: Plugins are independently created. If the plugin developer didn't add a batch process method, then it doesn't exist. QGIS core tools all have batch processing methods, so have a look at the "statistics by categories" tool and see if it does what you need.

Comment: Thank you for advice, it definitely helped. I used code below to run items iteratively. Only issue I had, when I open the excel file, it throws me a “repair warning”. After I click OK all calculations are there. But not sure why excel gives those warnings. >> import processing for itemfeature in listofShps: outputfullpath=os.path.dirname(itemfeature)+'\\'+os.path.basename(itemfeature)[:-4]+'.xlsx' processing.run('qgis:statisticsbycategories',{'CATEGORIES_FIELD_NAME' : [strCatagoryFieldName],'INPUT' : itemfeature,'VALUES_FIELD_NAME' : strValueFieldName,'OUTPUT' : outputfullpath} )

Comment: are you opening the .dbf portion of a shapefile?

Comment: I am using path of the " .shp " file as input parameters. Then after running the code, I am trying to open the result of the tool which is ".xlsx" which I specified in the code.